# On the Beta-t-EGARCH and the score

Tags: time-series, distributions, autoregressive, garch

I am going to define the Beta-t-EGARCH model utilizing the more familiar GARCH model as does Harvey in *Dynamic models for volatility and heavy tails* (2008), I hope this will serve the purpose to attract answerers.

The first-order Gaussian GARCH model is an observation driven model and it may be written as

$$y_t | Y_{t-1} \sim NID (0, \sigma_{t | t-1}^2 )$$
$$\sigma_{t+1 | t}^2 = \delta + \phi\sigma_{t | t-1}^2 + \alpha v_t, \quad \delta>0, \phi \ge \alpha, \alpha \ge 0. $$

where $y_t$ is an observation, $Y_{t-1}$ denotes observations up to and including $y_{t-1}$, $\phi = \alpha + \beta$, and $v_t = y_t^2 - \sigma_{t|t-1}^2$ is a martingale difference sequence.

The Beta-t-EGARCH model drops the Gaussianity assumptions and instead considers considers $y_t$ as having a conditional distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom. Also $v_t$ in the conditional variance equation is replaced by an other martingale difference sequence $v_t = \sigma_{t | t-1}^2 u_t$, where

$$u_t = \frac{(\nu +1) y_t^2}{(\nu -2)\sigma_{t | t-1}^2 + y_t^2} - 1, \quad -1 \le u_t \le \nu, \quad \nu>2.$$

Note that $u_t$ is the score (the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameter of interest) standardized by dividing by the information quantity, $I(\sigma_{t | t-1}^2) = \sigma_{t | t-1}^{-4}$.

Now my question is on this statement: Because the conditional score depends on past observations through $\sigma_{t|t-1}$, it can be broken down into two parts:

$$\frac{\partial f_t(y_t| Y_{t-1}; \psi)}{\partial \psi} = \frac{\partial f_t(y_t| Y_{t-1}; \sigma_{t|t-1})}{\partial \sigma_{t|t-1}} \frac{\partial \sigma_{t|t-1}}{\partial \psi}$$

where the notation $f_t(y_t ;\sigma_{t|t-1})$ indicates that the distribution of $y_t$ depends on the time varying parameter $\sigma_{t|t-1}$, and $\psi$ denotes the vector of parameters governing the dynamics. (I think $\psi = [\delta, \phi, \alpha, \nu]'$).

How is this chain rule applied? Could I have an example on $u_t$?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Thanks a lot for your reply, if the other parameters are constant I do not understand what sense to give to $\frac{\partial f_t(y_t| Y_{t-1}; \psi)}{\partial \psi}$ because $\psi$ is just a vector of constants right?